# Library not loaded error (libidn.11.dylib) when trying to install Homebrew

Tags: macos, installation, macports, homebrew

Trying to install Homebrew on Lion. When I do:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
Reason: image not found
```

I had MacPorts installed previously but uninstalled it and completely removed /opt/local
I also removed /opt/local from my PATH

Any idea why this error is happening?

Answer (score 8):

You built and installed `curl` into `/usr/local/bin`, but it linked against your MacPorts-installed `libidn`. You should delete `/usr/local/bin/curl`. You may also want to double-check everything else in `/usr/local/bin` to see if they have the same problem.

You may also need to check things in `/usr/local/lib` in case they link against MacPorts-installed libraries too. For example, curl may have a `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.dylib` that might link against stuff from `/opt/local/lib`.

Comment: Is there any easy way to check for other things that may be linking to MacPorts libraries?

Comment: @Callmeed: You can use `otool -L path` to check what libraries `path` links against. If you check `otool -L /usr/local/bin/curl` it should say that it's linked against something inside `/opt/local/lib`.

Comment: Yes please, if there is a fix.  I have a similar issue with a library that I removed, by deleting the folder, and now ffmpeg is complaining about it.

Answer (score 4):

For me, running `brew install libidn` did the trick

Comment: `brew reinstall libidn2` did the trick for me (the second version)

Answer (score 2):

Try `$ brew reinstall curl` , the curl dependency is reinstalled

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by running

```
brew upgrade
```

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/
ln -s libidn2.4.dylib libidn2.0.dylib
```

Answer (score -7):

The following fixed the specific issue for me:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/curl
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

If you already have an older homebrew installed:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

Stash any unbrewed files:

```
cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -f
```

#### brew doctor:

Install xcode cli tools from http://connect.apple.com.

Comment: i wish you had posted a warning that this removes everything you've installed under homebrew :(

Comment: Always be cautious when running a shell command you find on the internet. Especially if it includes `rm`