# rvm - how to re-install/remove ~/.rvm/usr/bin/curl, as its not working

Tags: ruby, curl, rvm

Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 on OSX but getting the error below.

Which seems to imply there is an issue with rvm's curl. Could it be an old asset from an earlier version of rvm?

I tried initially rvm install 1.9.3 and then rvm reinstall 1.9.3

```
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #making binaries executable - please wait
rubygems_setup version:latest rvm_ruby_string:ruby-1.9.3-p547 rvm_ruby_home:/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547 rvm_ruby_binary:/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
Running(15): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --max-time 1800 --connect-timeout 30 --retry-delay 2 --retry 3 -sS https://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/rubygems-update.json
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/usr/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
There was an error while trying to resolve rubygems version for 'latest'.
Halting the installation.
```

Using rvm v1.25.26 on OSX Mavericks

Installing ruby 2.1.2 worked ok after this.  Perhaps I needed to fix something around the rubygem latest check.

Tried rvm cleanup/repair all - no joy.

This machine was a time machine backup/restore from a few months ago - not sure if thats relevant.

TIA

Comment: Can you please post command used and FULL output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library not loaded error (libidn.11.dylib) when trying to install Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320298/library-not-loaded-error-libidn-11-dylib-when-trying-to-install-homebrew)

Comment: Thanks @UriAgassi, that seems close to what I want - however whats the best way to remove the rvm version of curl. Guess I could move it aside and see if it fixes itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving ~/.rvm/usr/bin/curl* out of the away and then rebuilding worked fine.

It did not recreate the rvm specific curl exe's - guess its happy with the system ones.

I did have macports installed previously, but now use homebrew - so I guess this was a hang up  from those days.