# Curl not working! dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew, dyld

I've looked at what may be a useful answer at [Library not loaded error (libidn.11.dylib) when trying to install Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320298/library-not-loaded-error-libidn-11-dylib-when-trying-to-install-homebrew).

However, I don't remember ever having purposely installed MacPorts.  Also, do not want to remove anything before I better understand what I would be doing.

Can anyone help me fix this without potentially doing damage.

[snapshot from my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rzqO.png)

Another snippet from console:

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$ brew install libidn
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$
```

Console log trying alvits' suggestions:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 18 18:10:39 on ttys002
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:~ JonMac$ otool -L /usr/local/bin/curl
/usr/local/bin/curl:
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.11.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:~ JonMac$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:Versions JonMac$ ls
2.0 Current
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:Versions JonMac$
```

Comment: Try `brew install libidn` to install the missing library required by curl

Comment: brew itself won't work:                                                                           'Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$ brew install libidn
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:bin JonMac$'

Comment: You are running `/usr/local/bin/curl` which was probably installed with `ruby` by `homebrew`. Running `otool -L /usr/local/bin/curl` will tell you what required libraries are needed by `/usr/local/bin/curl`. Check if `ruby` can run using `/usr/bin/curl`.

Comment: The installed `ruby` is missing as well. Did you just recently upgrade `OS X`? If you did, then you need to re-install `homebrew`. You should consider using the `XCode` command line tools when possible.

Comment: If you have recently upgraded `OS X` you;ll find a newer version of `ruby`. Check the content of this directory `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions`. Update the shebang of `homebrew` to reflect this new current version.

Comment: Hi Alvits!  It seems like i am still on ruby 2.0.0.  I am on OS X 11.  Should ruby have been upgraded when OS X 11 was installed (some time ago)?  I don't know what updating the shebang of 'homebrew' is.  I do have the 'XCode' command line tools installed.  How should I use these?  I haven't used them explicitly before.

Answer (score 1):

> The curl installed as part of your PHP installation is missing a
>   library that it expects, for some reason.
>
> You'll probably want to delete these PHP installs from /usr/local, as
>   chances are that they will interfere with future installs of software
>   through Homebrew, but that's up to use.
>
> Try explicitly using the OS X provide curl in /usr/bin/curl.

Based on [this response](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/22634)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't have PHP installed so that can't be the cause :(.